# CSS style priority

Tags: html, css

Before this question, I already search 'CSS priority' and I found following

The priority of inline style like `<div class="blue" style="color:red;">` is higher than class `blue` which define `color:blue;` And this rule is still work between tag and inline, i.e., inline has higher priority than tag.

Now I encounter a obstacle that I don't know. Here, simple example of my case.

First there are `<div>s`

```
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

and they have CSS

```
div { backgorund:url('path') no-repeat; }
div:nth-child(2n+1) { background-position: 'position A'; }
```

Now first and third `<div>` has same background image at `position A`.
Then I tried change third `<div>`'s background like

```
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div style="background-position: 'position B';"></div>
```

But the inline style of third `<div>` is not applied, still the `:nth-child`'s style occupy it. (third `<div>` still has background-position with 'position A')

I want to change third `<div>`'s background image that only has different 
background position. How can I do this?

(I know the priority of `inline style` is always higher than any others. But 
 in this case, it does not work)

for specification here my code

```
#courseList li { background:url('path') no-repeat; }
#courseList > li:nth-child(2n+1) {
    background-position:-5px -438px;
}
#courseList > li:nth-child(2n+2) {
    background-position:-187px -438px;
}

<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li>
        <div style='background-position:-551px -438px;'></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Different levels of CSS and the priority over each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5039020/different-levels-of-css-and-the-priority-over-each-other)

Comment: Are you actually using 'position A' and 'position B'?

Comment: @JefréN. Yes..? I use position A as -100px -20px for example and position B as similar

Comment: Could you modify your example to show **exactly** what your CSS rules look like?

Comment: @JefréN. oh... there is thing I don't know. your asking is big help to me! Before apply the `priority`, the applied tag is important. In my case I apply `inline style` on `child tag` not `target tag`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDITED to your scenario** (used background color for better illustration, you can simply replace them for position):

```css
#courseList>li:nth-child(2n+1) {
  background: red;
}

#courseList>li:nth-child(2n+2) {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<ul id="courseList">
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li style='background: blue;'>
    <div></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Here's a generic example:

```css
div {
  background: red;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}

div:nth-child(2n+1) {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div style="background: green;"></div>
```

Comment: Oh... there is big mistake. I apply inline style not on same position as your example. I applied it in the `child tag` thanks!!! I realize

Answer (score 0):

```
#courseList li { background:url('path') no-repeat; }
#courseList > li:nth-child(2n+1) {
    background-position:-5px -438px;
}  
#courseList > li:nth-child(2n+2) {
    background-position:-187px -438px;
}

<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li>
        <div style='background-position:-551px -438px;'></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Here is my case. The inline style of div do not work since `<div>` is not target I think.

And, next code follow the rule

```
#courseList li { background:url('path') no-repeat; }
#courseList > li:nth-child(2n+1) {
    background-position:-5px -438px;
}  
#courseList > li:nth-child(2n+2) {
    background-position:-187px -438px;
}

<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li style='background-position:-551px -438px;'>
        <div></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```